# How do i combine 2 jquery into 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to understand this jquery and I found 2 scripts I'd like to use, but can I combine them into 1? Currently I have them both under separate script tags.

Here is the first script

```
$(function(){
        $('#navigation_horiz').delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $('#navigation_horiz').naviDropDown({
        dropDownWidth: 'auto',  //the default width of drop down elements
        slideDownDuration: 600, //easing duration for slideDown
        slideUpDuration: 300 //easing duration for slideUp    
        });
});
```

Here is the second script

```
if (franchise_id==undefined) { //hide commish nav is not signed into site
     var franchise_id;
     document.write("<style type='text/css'>");
     document.write("#navigation_horiz ul li.commish { display: none; }");
     document.write("</style>");
} 
else if (franchise_id=="0000") { } //show commish nav is logged in as commish
else { // hide both if logged in as any other franchise
     document.write("<style type='text/css'>");
     document.write("#navigation_horiz ul li.commish { display: none; }");
     document.write("</style>");
}
```

tried to put in the same...example below and not working at all

```
    $(function(){
        $('#navigation_horiz').delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $('#navigation_horiz').naviDropDown({
        dropDownWidth: 'auto',  //the default width of drop down elements
        slideDownDuration: 600, //easing duration for slideDown
        slideUpDuration: 300 //easing duration for slideUp    
        });
});
if (franchise_id==undefined) { //hide commish nav is not signed into site
     var franchise_id;
     document.write("<style type='text/css'>");
     document.write("#navigation_horiz ul li.commish { display: none; }");
     document.write("</style>");
} 
else if (franchise_id=="0000") { } //show commish nav is logged in as commish
else { // hide both if logged in as any other franchise
     document.write("<style type='text/css'>");
     document.write("#navigation_horiz ul li.commish { display: none; }");
     document.write("</style>");
}
});
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just put them under the same script tag? You're not limited to one function per tag you know.

Comment: btw the second one is not even jQuery

Comment: tried to put in the same, but not working

Comment: @MikeShackelford I mean before second }); and after the first });

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. The first part is jQuery and the second part is raw Javascript, all under top namespace.

The only thing you need to note is: The jQuery code depends on jQuery lib and an independent plugin(naviDropDown?). So you must put the combined code **after** jQuery and the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can put them into a single tag, but it would be better to exclude them into a separate .js file and load it at the end of you document.

Comment: edited my first post, tried to combine but it would not work, have no idea how to create a js file on its own

Answer (score 0):

A function is only executable upon well, executing it.

If you are loading the second script on first load of your website, do not put the second script into the function if you do not intend on calling the function on load.

You should only combine scripts into the same function if and only if they are serving the same event.